# How to return each item of array separately js

Tags: javascript, react-native, viro-react

I have an array of Viro items that when displayed the onClick function does not work, I think because they are in an array when inputed into ViroARScene. Is there anyway to return all elements of the array separately in their  form?

**Edit**, sample code:

```
<ViroARScene>
 {ARObjects}
<ViroARScene/>
```

where {ARObjects} is an array of Viro items such as  and so on

```
ARObjects = [<ViroImage/>,<ViroPolygon/>,etc]
```

Comment: can you show us your codes??

Comment: `return` implies a `function` ... which has a single `return` value

Comment: Can you post sample array.. so we can see how exactly  array look like

Comment: You can use `Array.join()` function to join array elements into a string and then put it in `<ViroARScene><ViroARScene/>` or if your array have nested elements use loop and then do `Array.join()` at right time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use the forEach function, try this:

```
<ViroARScene>
 {ARObjects.forEach(element => return(element))}
</ViroARScene>
```